# Using two `done` functions in Ember mocha and Chai

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, chai

Using ember mocha and chai is it possible have two `dones`?

Trying to do something like this (doesn’t work)

```
function doSomething() {
  it('somethinng else', function(done) {
    var res = false
    Ember.run.later(() => {
      expect(res).to.be.true
      done()
    })
  })
}
it('somethinng', function(done) {
  doSomething()
  Ember.run.later(() => {
    //do other things
    done()
  })
})
```

But I don’t want to necessarily say `something` is actually done. What's the proper way to test two async functions in one mocha/chai test

A good alternative is if their is some functionality in mocha or chai that is equivalent to Qunit's assert.async https://api.qunitjs.com/async/

Answer (score 1):

Your initial attempt cannot work because Mocha does not allow nested `it` calls (i.e. `it` cannot call `it`). If you want to chain two asynchronous operations that take callbacks, you can just pass a custom callback to the first one and pass `it`'s `done` to the second one. Adapting your code:

```
function doSomething (done) {
    var res = false;
    Ember.run.later(() => {
        expect(res).to.be.true;
        done();
    });
}

it('something', function (done) {
    doSomething(function () {
        doSomethingElse(done);
    });
});
```

`doSomethingElse` will run after `doSomething` is done. I've assumed `doSomethingElse` is some asynchronous operation that takes a callback to notify completion.

Comment: Is this answer not the exact same as my working way, but still does not have the functionality I want? And is still only using one done operation